# Doing await directly on db operations will give undefined result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm directly doing await on asynchronous database operations. But the result is nothing. Here, is my code.

```
var channel_arr = await db.find({type:'pricing'},{channel_name:1},function(err,docs){
        if(err) {
            reject(err)
            return;
        }
        var c = []
        for(var o of docs){
            c.push(o['channel_name'])
        }
        return c;
    })
    alert(channel_arr)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You must `await`  a promise. And you won't need to pass a callback for that, that's the whole point.

Comment: See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) and [why you cannot `return` from arbitrary callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572?how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't provide callback.
You don't need surrounding Promise, instead you will add async function.
Approximate code:

```
async function someJob() {
  try {
    const channel_arr = await db.find({type:'pricing'},{channel_name:1});
    const c = [];
    for (const o of channel_arr) {
      c.push(o['channel_name']);
    }
    return c;
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Same code, but using Array.map:

```
async function someJob() {
  try {
    const docs = await db.find({type:'pricing'},{channel_name:1});
    return docs.map(el => el.channel_name);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: Why resolve/reject when the surrounding function is going to be marked `async` anyway?